# Force WP to use a certain search template

Tags: search

Any way to do this? I'd like for all the search results to be run through wp advanced search ( https://github.com/growthspark/wp-advanced-search ) so they appear on the wp advanced search page template instead of the default way provided by my theme.

Comment: The code in question doesn't seem to come with template, just with instructions how to integrate it. Please elaborate on what code you have implemented already and what you have trouble achieving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template include filter to use it on every search request.

Let's assume the advanced search page template you are using is `'wp-advanced-search.php'` you can use [`locate_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) to get its path:

```
add_action('template_include', 'advanced_search_tmpl');

function advanced_search_tmpl( $template ) {
  if ( is_search() ) {
     $t = locate_template('wp-advanced-search.php', false);
     if ( ! empty($t) ) $template = $t;
  }
  return $template;
}
```

Comment: Don't we still have to change the query itself because if you run a search in wp advanced search it looks like this in the url `http://localhost:8888/wordpress/?page_id=1706&search_query=test&orderby=blank&order=&wpas=1` but the regular search looks like `http://localhost:8888/wordpress/?s=test&submit=Search`

Comment: @Jagst3r15 you ask how to force to use a template, and I answered how to force to include a template. If you need the search offered by plugion, whay don't you use that plugin?