# Modifying the default search widget

Tags: widgets, search

I'm creating a plugin widget that does a different search from the normal default search widget. I copied the code from the default widget:

```
class new_search extends WP_Widget {


             function __construct() {
                    $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'widget_search', 'description' => __( "A search form for NextGen photos") );
                    parent::__construct('search', __('NGGSearch'), $widget_ops);
            }

            function widget( $args, $instance ) {
                    extract($args);
                    $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );

                    echo $before_widget;
                    if ( $title )
                            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

                    // Use current theme search form if it exists
                    get_search_form();

                    echo $after_widget;
            }

            function form( $instance ) {
                    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '') );
                    $title = $instance['title'];
    ?>
                    <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" /></label></p>
    <?php
            }

            function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
                    return;
            $instance = $old_instance;
                    $new_instance = wp_parse_args((array) $new_instance, array( 'title' => ''));
                    $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
                    return $instance;
            }





    } // end class example_widget
    add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("new_search");'));
    ?>
```

I'm having trouble finding where this default search widget calls the search.php function. Basically I want to create my own search.php function (AKA searchNew.php) and call it when the user hits search. Any ideas where search.php is called so I can replace it with a different file?

Edit: I've looked in the searchform.php file already (the one called by get_search_form) and nothing there seems to suggest it's calling search.php

Comment: Have a look @ this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/165494/22728

Comment: Thank you! Is there some way to modify the function.php file from within my plugin? I want to make this portable to other themes.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+filters

Answer (score 9):

You can hook into the 'get_search_form' action hook ( check out the "last option" part of the link below ).  Set the priority high enough to override anything created in a theme.

A plugin could look like ( from the link below ):

```
function my_search_form( $form ) {
    $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __( 'Search for:' ) . '</label>
    <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__( 'Search' ) .'" />
    </div>
    </form>';

    return $form;
}

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'my_search_form', 100 );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form#Theme_Form

Comment: The link says that I have to make this function in the functions.php file. Is there a way to make it inside a plugin folder? Thanks.

Comment: Of course - you can write the hook function in a plugin.

Comment: Bad news!: I don't know when but since search widget was replaced to new block search, the `get_search_form()` or **searchform.php** are no longer work. If your site still using old search widget, it still there with the same result as before but if you add new one, it will be block search. And I can't find how to modify block search element.

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way possible:

1. Create **searchform.php** in your theme. This will be used instead.
2. Add in your new search html

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <label for="search">Search in <?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
    <input type="image" alt="Search" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/search.png" />
</form>
```