# changing behaviour of get_search_form

Tags: functions, themes, search

I created a function to display a search box and named it `my_get_search_form()`. That is a copy of original `get_search_form()` function.

When I call the function, the output is this: `Search in http://localhost/wp_ex_3/ <AN EMPTY BOX> <A BROKEN IMAGE LINK>`.

How can I change this ugly display and to not show `http://localhost/wp_ex_3/`. I should to say that in the function definition there is not `"search in"` statement so another function caused this behaviour. source code of the function on `developer.wordpress.org`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/#source-code .

Comment: Why do you need another function to call the same `searchform.php`?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam I want it so that I can change its structure whitout changing the original function, for example maybe I want to add another box to the `formset`, something that by using the get_search_form() cannot achive.

Comment: To change the searchform you don't need to mess with `get_search_form()`, you just need to create your own search form in your theme and name it to `searchform.php`. You can see this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/165494/22728

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to add another function to get the search form. If you want to change the look of the search form or add another items you'll have to add the `searchform.php` to your theme.

It could look like this:

```
    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Suchen …" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="Suche nach:" />
        <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Suchen" />
    </form>
```

Everytime you call the `get_search_form()` function it will return the content of the `searchform.php` file. There you can add as many form fields as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the search behavior, then, all you need to do is add your own fields to the form

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://www.test.dev/">
<div>
<label for="s">Search for:</label>
<input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="sentence" />
<input type="hidden" value="product" name="post_type" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</div>
</form>
```

This search form, when submitted, will generate the following URL:

```
http://www.test.dev/?s={query}&sentence=1&post_type=product
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing default behavior or Search Form is necessary depending on Theme Design.
Here's an example what I do:

```
add_filter('get_search_form', 'elevation_search_form');

function elevation_search_form($form) {
    $form = '<form action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '" method="get" class="search-form">
        <input type="text" name="s" id="s" class="search" placeholder="Search for.." value="' . esc_attr( get_search_query() ) . '" required>
        <button type="submit" id="search-submit" class="search-submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>';
return $form;
}
```

Comment: It looks like this will give PHP syntax error. Can you please update your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO **it should be use "add_filter" as Liton Arefin wrote**, which should be added inside functions.php of own created theme of Wordpress.
It should override all variables need to override following with original function get_search_form() which is normally placed in:
<worpdress_name_project>\wp-include\general-template.php
Please scroll down the general-template.php file where is placed line:

```
function get_search_form( $args = array() )
```

...and then (for example) if You want to change default displaying text, which  normally placed just next to (before) edit element (part where is typing words for search) please look forward for line looking something like...
(and please check the places where "Search for:" is changed (override) for "SEARCH FOR:")

```
$search_form_template = locate_template( 'searchform.php' );
if ( '' !== $search_form_template ) 
   {
   (...)
   if ( 'html5' === $format ) 
      {
      $form=(...)
      class="screen-reader-text" (...)
      /* translators: Hidden accessibility text. */
      _x( 'SEARCH FOR:', 'label' ) .
      (...)
      }
```

...BUT DO NOT try to change this part of Wordpress CMS (or ANY other files expect Your own theme files), because new version of Wordpress CMS will probably override (delete) that tries of changing search form. So...
**In my humble opinion (and probably the most practical way) is to use own actions inside functions.php of Your own theme**, because after any update of Wordpress in that case it should not be replaced by new versions of Wordpress (with any new function etc.).
New instance of Wordpress will do not touch files of Your theme, which should be placed inside:

[Wordpress_project_name]\wp-content\themes[Your_name_of_WP_Theme]

It is all detailed described on the official Wordpress site:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/

1. just scrool down up to text:
   "A last option is to write a custom function (in your functions.php file) and hook that function to the get_search_form action hook."
2. Create action hook as described into Your own functions.php inside Your own theme.
3. Change anything You need (but avoid to change the "s" parameter as Wordpress Developers desrcibed).
4. Save and reset Your site.

Voila.. :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/265190)

Answer (score 0):

However if somebody is looking for methode with old good tags of HTML, here is an answer i tested and it is working:

1. Create file named:
   searchform.php
   inside Your theme directory.
2. Copy and paste following code - BUT after copy don't forget changing ANY "[" for "less sign" and "]" for "more sign" because of html/php tags... ;)

```
[form role="search"  
      method="get" 
      class="search-form" 
      action="[?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?]"]    
    [label]
        [div class="screen-reader-text" for="s"]
             [?php
             echo _x( 'LABEL SHOW BEFORE EDIT WINDOW', 'label' ); 
             ?]
        [/div]
        [input type="search" 
             class="search-field" 
             placeholder="[?php 
                               echo esc_attr_x( 'TEXT SHOW INSIDE EDIT WINDOW - cleared after typing', 'placeholder' ); 
                           ?]" 
             value="[?php 
                         echo get_search_query(); 
                     ?]" 
             name="s" 
             title="[?php 
                         echo esc_attr_x( 'BUMBLE CLOUD HELP SHOW WHEN MOUSE OVER', 'label' ); 
                     ?]"/]
    [/label]
    [input type="submit" 
           class="search-submit" 
           value="[?php 
                       echo esc_attr_x( 'THIS IS TEXT SHOW ON YOUR SEARCH BUTTON', 'submit button' ); 
                   ?]" /]
[/form]
```

3. Don't forget delete (or change) labeled parts here something like "BUMBLE CLOUD HELP (...)" and so on ;)
4. Don't change "s" parameter of search form... Seems like Wordpress doesn't like it... ;)
5. Enjoy... :)

Voila :)

P.S. Of course good searchform is just one part of story, and the other part is create a good search.php which should be responsible for showing results of search procedure... ;)
if so.. look around of some real EASY theme for analyse, like "Write" Wordpresse theme from Themegraphy, link below:

https://themegraphy.com/wordpress-themes/write/