# Page has no template

Tags: search, conditional-tags, template-hierarchy

I've created a custom search for my custom posts, using the accepted answer from [Creating a search form for custom fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165478/creating-a-search-form-for-custom-fields).

However, I'm struggling with the resulting page - I need to conditionally enqueue some javascript, but the results page fails every conditional I throw at it. I eventually installed the plugin "What Template Am I Using", and it too, says the following:

Post Type: not set

Front: No

Home: No

404: No

Search: No

and the "template" section is blank (which is kind of what I found - various `get_the_template()` functions are come back blank.

What's going on? And is there another way I can conditionally enqueue my javascript?

[EDIT]:
The conditionals I used are:

- `if( is_search() ) {echo "<h1>Foo Search</h1>"; }`
- `if( is_page_template( 'content-search.php' ) ) {echo "<h1>Bar Template</h1>"; }`
- `if( is_page_template( 'search-advanced.php' ) ) {echo "<h1>FooBar Template</h1>"; }`
- `if( is_archive( ) ) {echo "<h1>Foo Archive</h1>"; }`

None of the above evaluated as `true`. I tried these both in the search results page, just before the loop, and in `functions.php`.

Here is my search form: http://pastebin.com/Cq177zWV

And here is my search results page (search-advanced.php): http://pastebin.com/FxFpmECH

And here is the snippet from my `functions.php` (via [Creating a search form for custom fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165478/creating-a-search-form-for-custom-fields).):

`function shr_load_custom_search_template(){
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['search'] ) && $_REQUEST['search'] == 'advanced' && ! is_admin() ) {
        require('search-advanced.php');
        die();
    }
}
add_action('init','shr_load_custom_search_template');`

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your code?  Mainly the search form markup.  You should be able to use `is_search()` here.

Comment: The search results are typically shown via search.php in your theme. What conditionals did you throw at the enqueue script? (agree with @jdm2112 that is_search() typically should work). Where did you put those conditionals?

Comment: The `is_` conditionals are set after the query runs, on the `wp` action. You are halting execution on the `init` action, before the main query runs, which is way too early. Your search should hook `pre_get_posts` to modify the main query rather than generating a new query in a template file.

Comment: Thanks @Milo - will try that first thing in the morning!

Comment: I found the problem - I wasn't actually submitting the value "s" (I had changed the standard <input type=submit> to a button instead. As soon as I added a hidden input with value "s", is_search() started evaluating true.