# Pagination not working for Custom search form & custom result template

Tags: wp-query, pagination, search, forms

I am using custom search form and custom template to display the results according to the solution given in [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165478/creating-a-search-form-for-custom-fields)
Everything is working perfect except the pagination which  doesn't seem to work at all

**Overview**

- Custom post type    : job_listing
- Custom taxonomy     : job_listing_type
- custom fields as key: _job_location

Here is the code for search form :

```
<form method="get" id="advanced-searchform" role="search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="search" value="advanced">

        <select id="my-select1" class="js-example-basic-single isotopeselect" data-filter-group="proyectos" multiple="multiple" name="terms[]">

        <?php foreach ($job_terms as $job_term): ?>
          <option value=".<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', str_replace('&', 'and', html_entity_decode($job_term)));?>"><?php echo $job_term;?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        </select>    
        <button type="submit"><span>search</span></button>
    <input type="hidden" name="job_listing" value=""/>
</form>
```

Here is the search result template

```
<?php 
get_header();
$terms=array();
$all=($_REQUEST); 


if(isset($_REQUEST["terms"])){
    $myterms=$all["terms"];
    foreach ($myterms as $myterm) {
    $myterm=str_replace(".","",$myterm);
    $terms[]=$myterm;    
    }
}

if($terms){
    $tax_query[] =  array(
                        array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_type',
                        'field' => 'name',
                        'terms' => $terms
                      ) );
}

$post_type = 'job_listing';
$paged= (get_query_var('paged' )) ? get_query_var('paged'):1;
$args         =  array(
    'paged'=>$paged,
    'post_type'=>$post_type,
    'posts_per_page'=>1, 
    'tax_query' => $tax_query,
    );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );     
if($loop->have_posts()):?>

    <div class="my-services">
        <?php    
        while($loop->have_posts()):$loop->the_post();              
        the_title();

        endwhile;
        ?>

    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
    <div class="pagination" id="blog-pagination">
      <span class="previous" ><?php previous_posts_link( '&larr;Newer', $loop->max_num_pages  ); ?></span>
      <span class="next"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older &rarr;', $loop->max_num_pages  ); ?></span>
    </div>
    <?php wp_reset_query();?>     

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Result on initial search, url is like

```
http://example.com/?search=advanced&terms%5B%5D=.Eat&job_listing=
```

After i hit next  then url becomes

http://example.com/page/2/?search=advanced&terms%5B0%5D=.Eat&job_listing

but nothing happens, result remains same

I have never done this before so please help me out on this

Comment: The other answer on that question is actually a much better solution, it modifies the main query rather than generating a new one in the template, which is always fraught with disaster when dealing with pagination.

Comment: @Milo I am also thinking of using that solution but somehow  correct template heirarchy is not working as explained in other problem here  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/264648/archive-or-taxonomy-pages-not-working-for-custom-post-type

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the plugin and something you may need to take up with their support.

Answer (score 1):

i've seen this: [next_posts_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link)

You must use wp_reset_postdata when use new WP_QUERY(), and this

```
<div class="pagination" id="blog-pagination">
  <span class="previous" ><?php previous_posts_link( '&larr;Newer', $loop->max_num_pages  ); ?></span>
  <span class="next"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older &rarr;', $loop->max_num_pages  ); ?></span>
</div>
```

go into if($loop->have_posts()):?> condition