# Archive or taxonomy pages not working for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives, template-hierarchy

I am trying to built archive templates for my theme , I am using plugin wp-job-manager which gives me following custom post type & taxonomies

1. **custom post type**     : job_listing
2. **1st custom taxonomy**  : job_listing_type
3. **2nd custom taxonomy**  : job_listing_category

Name of templates i am using is

- taxonomy-job_listing_type.php
- taxonomy-job_category_type.php
- archive-job_listing.php

But still when I try to  view any taxnomy term , still none of the above template is being used instead I am redirected to archive.php

As per wp-job-manager I have added this line to enable the theme support

```
add_theme_support( 'job-manager-templates' );
```

I have no idea why this is happening though I have used wp job manager a lot of times..

Looking forward for some help

thanks

Comment: Did you refresh your permalinks after creating new archive pages?

Comment: @AniruddhaGawade thanks for the speedy reply..   Ya i did it many times as I am facing this issue for a lot of days .. but archive.php was serving my purpose till now .. But now I need that fixed...

Comment: Did you check the file/folder structure, as specified in the plugin for overriding templates? And make sure the plugin allows to override it's templates.

Comment: hey I checked there are no archive or taxonomy templates provided by plugin that is why it is using archive.php of my theme. So I guess that won't work.. But just meanwhile talking to you I tried taxonomy.php and it is working but taxonomy-job_listing_type.php  is not

Comment: Okay, can you add `add_theme_support` with priority -1 to init? try if that helps. And just for debugging purpose add your file in plugin and see if that is read.

Comment: hey I tried something like this add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'w3job_setup',-1 );
 
if ( ! function_exists( 'w3job_setup' ) ):
 
function w3job_setup() {
 
add_theme_support( 'job-manager-templates' );
}
endif;     and then resaved the permalinks,, but nothing happens.. gonna try that plugin debugging