# Steps for custom data retrieval

Tags: customization, search

I'm trying to create a data retrieval field within a page. This would be a single input text box, which would query a non-WordPress table and return the result.

I have done custom retrieval in the past using shortcodes, but cannot find anything that includes a query field. The closest I could find is [searching custom fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/165478/16780), however that is using internal tables and `WP_Query`.

Would the following steps be correct for what I'm trying to achieve?

1. Create search form
2. Function to process search
3. Create result file with fetch from custom table

Comment: If you querying a non-wp table, you can still use wpdb and do it on a shortcode like you did before.  See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb.  Basically use the global $wpdb and $wpdb->prefix.'yourtablename' and remember to sanitize the text field https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data#Sanitizing:_Cleaning_User_Input and use the wpdb prepare method https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/ to pass the variable to the select statement.