# how to make search with two input boxes

Tags: search

```
<input type="search" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $unique_id ); ?>" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder', 'twentytwenty' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" />
```

Default search have only one input field search with name="s" but I want to add another input field so user can input there age or pincode manually and result will be relative.

```
<input type="search" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $unique_id ); ?>" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder', 'twentytwenty' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" />

<input type="search" id="id" class="search-field" placeholder="age" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s2" />
```

now user can enter there name age in both input field.

Comment: You want that user can find make search on the basis of keyword and pin-code, and keyword and pincode will relatively used on basis of `OR`. Am I right?

Comment: i think you are not clear about it. i want both input field like name and age.

Comment: Results will be shown on basis of both the inputs using `AND` relation in query.

Comment: i need guide how to do it.

Comment: You have to create the functionality for this as WordPress search does not support such kind of search. Functions to be written will be based on the way you want to use for showing data that is, using ajax or using page reload. Tell me, what way you want to use.

Comment: on the page reload. /?s=name dont know how the second argument will be pass. may be something like /?s=name?location=110025

Comment: You don't need to add any argument on your own. Just add another field in search form and you will be able to get it in your search url. It will be shown like: `/?s=name&age=age`

Comment: that is why i add the question i need help to add code and displaying in argument search.php

Comment: I need to know the kind of data on which you are making search only then I will be able to create a useful script for you.

Comment: yes http://lifecoachnearme.co.uk/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a search form for custom fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165478/creating-a-search-form-for-custom-fields)

Comment: @MayeenulIslam This one seems to be a good one.