# problem with setting tax_query in pre_get_posts

Tags: pre-get-posts, tax-query

I tried to make an advanced search which shows posts in a custom post type (book) with custom taxonomy (writer) that user wants. This code works in a query in a page but didn't work in pre_get_posts. whats the problem?

```
function advanced_search_query( $query ) {
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['search'] ) && $_REQUEST['search'] == 'advanced' && ! is_admin() && $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'book' );
        $search_case = $_GET['book-writer'];
        $tax_query = array(
                                                array(
                                                    'taxonomy' => 'writer',
                                                    'field'    => 'name',
                                                    'terms'    => $search_case,
                                                )
                                            );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'advanced_search_query' );
```

Comment: this is already possible out of the box using URLs such as this: `example.com/writer/jane-doe/?s=booktitle`, that URL shows all books in the `jane-doe` taxonomy that match the search term `booktitle`. There's no need for a `search` parameter, or a custom template, WordPress already did this with `s` and `search.php` as well as the fundamentals of how URLs and parameters in WordPress work. You could even do `example.com/?s=booktitle&post_type=book&writer=jane-doe`, and if you wanted a custom URL you could map it to a rewrite rule

Comment: Also, `is_search` should be `is_search()`, and `$_REQUEST` is problematic, did you know it can also match environment variables and cookies? Imagine accidentally setting a cookie and finding almost every page on your site now has this extra taxonomy clause without explanation

Comment: I think `$query->is_search` is true. I found this part on this page: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165478/creating-a-search-form-for-custom-fields

Comment: Also I don't know writer name to use the WordPress URLs. the user search a word to find it between writer names.

Comment: Furthermore why this code works in page query but didn't work in pre_get_posts?